# The MySQL bit data type displays as 0x00. Why?

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL database with multiple tables with some records having the BIT(1) data type. When I query the records in the MySQL shell however, the data is displayed as 0x00. Why is this? Anyone else have this issue?

Comment: Why is it an issue for you? Where does this representation makes problems?

Comment: It is always better than what mariadb does do.  It tries to show the character which is not visible.....